# Create custom Excel pie chart labels

Tags: c#, excel

I'm programmatically creating pie charts in Excel using C#. I need to add some custom labels for the slices. Basically, I want the labels for slices on the left hand side of the pie to start at the top left of the chart area and go down. On the right side the same thing. My question is, how can I find the midpoint of the arc of the slice to know what side of the chart the label should go on?

I thought if I got the points in the series I could find it, but I haven't seen it.

```
Point p = (Point)oSeriesCollection.Item(1).Points(1);
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Realized I should probably include more detail. When I say "custom labels" what I mean is that I'll place text boxes on the chart using something like the code below. From all of the searching I've done I haven't found another way to do it (using the built in data labels). If there is a way to resize and place the built in datalabels I'm all ears for any tips on how to make that happen.

```
oChart.Chart.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 100, 100).TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Text = "text";
```

**Edit 2**
For anyone interested here is the answer I found over at an Excel forum (it was using VBA). The line that adds the text box is just a place holder, but if center is between 0 and 180 it will go on the right side, otherwise it will go on the left and, of course, I'll have to move them down with each one. Another thing to consider is that if the pie has been rotated the center value will need to be modified by the FirstSliceAngle.

```
double total=0;
foreach (object item in (Array)oSeriesCollection.Item(1).Values)
{
    total+=Convert.ToDouble(item);
}

double runtotal=0;
for (int x=1; x <= ((Array)oSeriesCollection.Item(1).Values).GetUpperBound(0); x++)
{
    object item = ((Array)oSeriesCollection.Item(1).Values).GetValue(x);
    double center = (runtotal + Convert.ToDouble(item) / 2) / total * 360;
    runtotal+=Convert.ToDouble(item);

    chart.Chart.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 50, 10).TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Text = "some text";
}
```